# rbind() with rows_selected in DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am building an R app and came across the DT package recently. I am pressed for time and therefore, after spending a couple of hours on stackoverflow with no luck, I decided to ask the question. server part of my app has twp parts - one where a datatable is rendered after a few calculations and another where there is for loop for the selected rows and results for each run are combined using rbind to get a dataframe.

```
     server<-function(input, output, session){
      ts_info<-eventReactive(input$goButton,{
        #Do something with one of the textInputs and return a dataframe called data1
      return(data1)

      })

      output$results<-renderDT(ts_info())


      all_data<-data.frame() #create an empty dataframe

      dataset <- eventReactive(input$results_rows_selected,{

      timeseriespath<-ts_info()$ts_path[input$results_rows_selected] #instead of row index get the value from column 'ts_path' for the selected rows

       TS_URL<-read_html("http://xxxxxxtimeseriespath//yyy")
       tbls<-html_nodes(TS_URL,"table")
       tbls_ls <- TS_URL %>%
      html_nodes("table") %>%
      .[1] %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE)

      data2<-data.frame(tbls_ls)
      all_data<-rbind(all_data,data2) #rbind with the existing all_data dataframe
        return(all_data)
      })


      output$finaldataset <- renderTable({ 
        dataset()
      })


}
```

When I have only row selected, dataset() correctly appears on the app. The moment I select more than one row, I get the error below-
Warning: Error in doc_parse_file: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].
Essentially, I just want to combine all "data2" which result from iteration of input$results_rows_selected. 
Could someone please help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Please show content of `input$results_rows_selected`. Also, the *test* object is never used and if it is, *test* would be a vector (i.e., *ts_path* column of data frame) and not a filtered row data frame.

Comment: @Parfait : Sorry I meant that ts_path is a value and then there are a few lines of code which use this value to return a dataframe. Wouldn't input$results_rows_selected return the row index of the selected row?

Comment: Once again, *test* is never used in posted code. Not sure how *this works great*. If `input$results_rows_selected` is an integer vector, then you are indexing the vector *ts_path*, not data frame. Come to think of it, not sure why you are using `rbind` as *all_data* will always be empty. Maybe you meant to iterate through `input$results_rows_selected`?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a full reproducible example with sample data, but which line is the warning occurring on (i.e. which call is resulting in the warning)?

Comment: @Parfait Yes, I want to iterate through input$results_rows_selected and combine the results of all iterations. My apologies for not being clear, I am very to Shiny.

Comment: If `input$results_rows_selected` is a vector of integers (please confirm this as asked above), then there is no need to iterate or `rbind`. Just row index the data frame to return *all* columns (not just `ts_path`): `return(ts_info()[input$results_rows_selected,])`